# IP address detection tool

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, ethernet

I need some help with a mini project of mine considering checking ip addresses. The main goal is to be able to either plug a device in between the router and the end device (a PC for example) in order to simply display the address assigned by the router to this specific ethernet cable. Alternatively if the former would dramatically impact the throughput of the cable itself I would settle on needing to unplug the end device in order to plug the said microcontroller so I can check the IP and plug the cable back into the end device.

I need it for quality of life at work where we have a lot of Nvidia Jetson boards all connected in a very unorderly fashion all around the office, 90% of the time they are set up for remote access and need their IP address to connect. I could just set static IP but it would not solve the problem in the long run since they have their system wiped very often.

Having such thing always on hand would make my life easier, I know that there are dedicated tools for that but they are often either too expensive for me to bother buying them or are simply an overkill in what they offer, apart from that, come on it would just be cool.

I only need help READING the address from the cable, the simpler the better. I would greatly appreciate a recommendation for a board that would best fit this, I usually use the ESP and STM boards so I prefer those.

Comment: IP addresses are not assigned to cables, they are assigned to devices. Cables are layer 1, IP is layer 3.

Comment: i know that but isn't there any way i could just listen to the tcp requests in order to determine the IP address assigned to the device?

Comment: Can't you just ask the router? If it has no management interface, get one that does. This question is better suited to https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: And if you can't replace the router, you can always use a dedicated device (like a raspberry pi or server), as a DHCP server, that supports mac based DHCP pinning. Then unless the wiping also regenerates the MAC address, the IP will stay static.

Comment: Any old laptop, or mini computer like Jetson, could be used, as long as it has two network interfaces and the interfaces are configured correctly and then run IP packet capturing software to catch and show DHCP packets.

Comment: Another thing you can do is write down the MAC addresses of the Jetsons - which won't change - and then put "one big" sniffer in line with the router to record the IP addresses it hands out. Or, if your router has the ability to see the IP and MAC addresses (some do have this feature in their GUI) you can just read them off there, no sniffing needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Basics

If we imagine the typical case of the endpoint devices on a twisted-pair ethernet segment:

- At one end is a switch, typically built in to the router hardware R
- At the other end is a device A, B, C
- We insert our device at point X

  ```
   ISP
    |
    R
    |
  --+---+---+---+---
        |   |   |
        X   |   |
        |   |   |
        A   B   C
  ```

A network sniffer on this wire will see a small amount of traffic between the device and the router itself (such as DHCP), and a much larger amount of traffic from the device to its communicating partners (typically HTTP).

If there is no peer-to-peer communication within the network (A to B etc) Ethernet traffic at X will be either from the ether address of R to the ether address of A or vice versa. We sniff for anything characteristic: I'd expect, for example, no DHCP except for A, no DNS except from A. At the simplest, make a table of all the IP addresses seen on the packets, the most common one should be A. A rough and ready script is easily made in Bourne shell or Python.

On the other hand, if you have a lot of traffic within the network (i.e., between A and B) you might need to have an ethernet bridge at X so you can see which end the frame is coming from.

### Rasperry Pi + TCPDump

A device suitable for this would be a Ethernet switch with a monitoring port and a display unit such as a Raspberry Pi running basic network traffic analysis. You start with TCPDump/TShark. Any two-Ethernet Linux computer will do the bridge function, and also run the TCPDump/whatever.

It should be able to do this in an afternoon with a Raspberry Pi or similar. It's possible to build a microcontroller "device" for it but it's a lot of work for not much benefit over a Pi in a cute box with a small screen and a good `/etc/rc.local`. Getting it to work is all about the ethernet switch monitoring port, not the sniffing and IP address extraction. You start by reading the capture set up requirements at [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Ethernet).

### Building a Circuit

- Get a powerful MCU which can handle wire-speed ethenet at your desired speed
- With two ethernet ports
- Some kind of output display
- Program it as a bridge which copies all frames from each side to the other (this is harder than it seems at first: you have to queue the frames in case the other side is busy.)
- Look for IP packets in the ether frames
- Pull out IP address
- Sort / Display

This device doesn't have to communicate at all on the ethernet, but it might want to for logging results etc.  You might find it good to look for [LLDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Discovery_Protocol) or [CDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cisco_Discovery_Protocol) type traffic too, if your switches have it, as this will tell you what socket you're connected to.

However you put one together, it can be really handy to have a small device to plug in to a wire to see what's happening.

*Obligatory postscript noting that monitoring Ethernet traffic has ethical considerations and in many jurisdictions legal ones too.*